# How to setup in `~/.vimrc` a mapping for `colorscheme` to toggle `solarized` between `dark` and `light`?

Tags: vim, colors, vimrc, vim-plugins, vimscript

**How to setup in `~/.vimrc` a mapping for `colorscheme` to toggle `solarized` between `dark` and `light`?**

Both `background` and `colorscheme` in `~/.vimrc` are badly misbehaving!

I have setup solarized to work on vim and it can manually toggle between background light/dark. My general settings in `~/.vimrc` are:

> Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'      *"I use `plug.vim`*
>
> syntax enable
>
> set background=light
>
> set t_Co=256
>
> let g:solarized_termcolors=256

Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04.; xterm and works well with 256 colors.

I'm trying to map in `~/.vimrc` `background` toggling. For this purpose :help solarized (in vim) suggests to use:

```
call togglebg#map("<F9>")
```

but this doesn't work because it changes the `colorscheme` from `solarized` to `default` (my intention was to toggle only in `solarized` between `dark` and `light`).

So I remove from ~/.vimrc `call togglebg#map("<F9>")` and replaced it with what most google/superuser/vim.wikia commentators, in various flavors, have suggested with the following:

```
function! BgToggleSol()
    if (&background == "light")
        set background=dark 
    else
        set background=light 
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <leader>sz :call BgToggleSol()<cr>
colorscheme solarized
```

But this has the same problem (that toggling resets `colorscheme` to `default`). While if `colorscheme solarized` is executed directly after `set background=...` in the `if else endif` clause then the `background` stops toggling between `dark`/`light`.

I must have exhausted nearly all possibilities, but the problem is still not going away.

Any suggestion is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have some colorscheme autocommands that might change the bg behind your back? check the output of `:au ColorScheme` and try explicitly `:noa colors solarized`

Comment: `:au ColorScheme` executes a whole bunch of outputs in vim (too long here to place due to restricted space). The AutoCommands listed are: `ColorScheme`, `fugitive_blame`, `airline`, `indent_guides`, `vimwiki`, `indentLine`, and again `ColorScheme`.  Also it appears to me that `:noa colors solarized` disables (partially, visually) `airline`. What's next pls?

Comment: What do you mean with what is next? disabling colorscheme autocommands, does that work with toggling the background setting?